jpackage cannot build JavaFX installer with Spring Boot and Gradle
I am trying to build installer package for a Spring Boot JavaFX application (Mac and Windows) by following these steps below. However, during the execution of ./gradlew jpackage command, I get several errors e.g. "module not found: javafx.base requires javafx.base;", and when I debug I also get "Unsupported class file major version 66".
Tried several workarounds mentioned on SO, etc. to fix, it does not make and still the same problems. I am using Java 21 and not sure if there are some incompatibility with this. Here is the config and steps I followed:
build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.26.0'
}

group = 'com.company'
version = '1.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = '21'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // Spring Dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    // External Dependencies
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.17.2'
    implementation 'io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.72.Final:osx-aarch_64'
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:3.0.5'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:2.3.230'

    // Test Dependencies
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

javafx {
    version = "21"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ] // 'javafx.base' (also tried with this)
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.company.accountmanagement' // Replace with your main module name
    mainClass = 'com.company.AccountManagementApplication.main' // Replace with your main class
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
    jpackage {
        jpackageHome = '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home'
        installerType = 'dmg'
        imageOptions = []
        installerOptions = [
                '--resource-dir', "${projectDir}/src/main/resources",
                '--vendor', 'Company Name'
        ]
        installerName = 'AccountManagement'
        appVersion = '1.0.0'
        if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows) {
            installerOptions += ['--win-dir-chooser', '--win-menu', '--win-shortcut']
            imageOptions += ["--icon", "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/icon.ico"]
        }
        if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().macOsX) {
            installerOptions += ['--mac-package-name', 'AccountManagement']
            imageOptions += ["--icon", "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/icon.icns"]
        }
    }
}

tasks.jlink {
    group = 'distribution'
}

tasks.jpackage {
    group = 'distribution'
}



Build the application:

./gradlew build



Create the runtime image and installer package:

./gradlew jpackage


It may also be related to module-info.java, but it seems fine as far as I checked:
module com.company.accountmanagement {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.context;
    requires jasypt.spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;

    opens com.company.accountmanagement to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.company.accountmanagement;
}


Trying to create a modular app using Sring is not something I recommend as Spring (6) is not currently well architected you easily enable that IMO. Consider a non-modular app packaged using the runtime plugin instead.

@jewelsea Thanks for your answer. Could you post an example based on Spring Boot + JavaFX app? On the other hand, that plugin also uses jpackage and I am not sure if it will also throw the same exception. Because I also tried to use jlink as mentioned on JetBrains page and get the same error.

@jewelsea It may also be good option to use one of these SDKs, I checked and both of them have JDK 21 versions. So, after installing them, and removing JavaFX SDK and plugin, how to build installer package for Mac and Windows?

No, I don’t use Gradle and try to use Maven instead, so I won’t normally post an answer for a technology I try to avoid.

Ok, then it would also be possible to convert it to Gradle. Could you please just let me know about the necessary steps to build installer package for a Spring Boot Java FX project?

For Maven, see How to make a Windows/MacOS/Linux installer for JavaFX & Spring Boot application or JPackageScriptFX.  For Gradle, the runtime plugin repository links to projects that package using the plugin for Sprin and JavaFX, though not both together, that is something you would need to work out yourself.

I will check, on the other hand I wanted to try Liberica JDK (full) first, but in addition to using it as project sdk, should I also remove module-info.java file or some JavaFX plugins from the project?

If you use Liberica Full JDK, that includes JavaFX, so you can remove the JavaFX plugins, JavaFX SDK and any VM switches that use JavaFX modules.  Liberica JDK also includes jpackage which allows you to package from a script or command line if you prefer that to the Gradle runtime plugin, or you can use the Gradle runtime, as you choose.

As an aside, --resources-dir is not the same thing as "Java resources", so passing src/main/resources to that option is incorrect. The --resources-dir option is a relatively advanced option meant for replacing certain jpackage resources (e.g., configuration files used by the platform-specific tools jpackage uses behind the scenes to create the installer packages).

@Slaw Thanks, then which parameter should be used to pass Java resources?

None. Such resources should be embedded alongside the Java code. Note this is typically default behavior, so you shouldn't have to do anything special as long as you put all non-*.java resources under src/main/resources.

Could you please check this question? I think we could probably fix the issue at the last stage with the help of you. Thanks in advance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78959913/installed-package-cannot-be-initialised-on-mac-while-jar-is-working

As per my guess, you might be running this on a different JDK (lower) jdk
Ensure JDK Compatibility: Verify that both your build and runtime environments are using the same JDK version. For JDK 21, ensure that the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility in your build.gradle are set to 21.
gradle
sourceCompatibility = '21'
targetCompatibility = '21'


Thanks, I also tried to use it before and retried again now, but still getting "error: module not found: javafx.base requires javafx.base;" error.
